# i want to find bookshelf like demo

Tags: iphone

i used to have a bookshelf demo downloaded from the apple's official site . But now i lost it and couldn't find it back . Does anybody come over it. please let me know , just give me a link. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub project maybe can help you:

https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

[This example is for an iPad app].